# When the FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() might be null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am passing a `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag);` and I don't know when the `getSupportFragmentManager()` could be null. Is it possible for this function to return null when the activity is on screen?
Should I check if the `getSupportFragmentManager() == null` before passing it to this function?

Comment: I think when developing android application with java, it's a good practise to check null exception as most as possible.

Comment: Actually, I check it but I want to know if there is any reason for that.

Comment: Have you debugged it ?

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't know how to make this null to happen.

Comment: If you're not using kotlin, definitely check if supportFragmentManager is null, because it can occur when activity is on background, or also in fragment when fragment was not been attached to activity